# Updating realm object having primary key

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, realm

I am trying to update a realm object with primary key. Now keep in mind I am not updating the primary key but only another field in there. Below is my my Object :

```
class UserData : Object {

@objc dynamic var name: String? = nil
@objc dynamic var bio: String? = nil
@objc dynamic var username: String? = nil
@objc dynamic var phone: String? = nil
@objc dynamic var uid : String? = nil
@objc dynamic var imageL: Data? = nil

override static func primaryKey() -> String {
    return "uid"
}

}

extension UserData {


func writeToRealm(){
    try? RealmService.uirealm.realm.write {
        RealmService.uirealm.realm.add(self, update: true)
    }
}

func DeleteFromRealm(object: Results<UserData>){
    try? RealmService.uirealm.realm.write {
        RealmService.uirealm.realm.delete(object)
    }
}

}
```

This is How I am instantiating the realm Service in my program :

```
class RealmService {

static let uirealm = RealmService()

private var _initRS = try! Realm()

var realm: Realm! {
    return _initRS
}
}
```

I am trying to update the "bio" property of the object but am Contiuiosly given an

> exception for "unable to update primary key"

Now, I really don't understand why I am being thrown this error even though
I am not updating the primary key in the object.

Extra Notes:

I am updating the realm object on every observable change of the firebase instance. So this is the area where i am having the problem. Because there is going to be a only one write realm instance everytime a change occurs.

Code for the same :

```
FBDataservice.ds.REF_USERS.child(uuid).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.hasChild("credentials") {
            if let snap = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
                if let cred = snap["credentials"] as? Dictionary<String, Any> {

                    let u = User(userid: uuid, userData: cred)
                    self.usercache.uid = uuid
                    self.usercache.bio = u.aboutme
                    self.usercache.writeToRealm()
                }
            }
        }
//            RealmService.uirealm.realm.refresh() ------> No sure about this
    })
}
```

Comment: Please, upload code how you try to update "bio", I think you wrong in this code.

Comment: are you asking for the firebase code?

Comment: updated the firebase code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is in this line

```
self.usercache.uid = uuid
```

Because self.usercache is already a Realm object, so when you update it's uid => it throw exception.

Instead of re-use self.usercache, try create a new UserData object

Comment: I tried that. Thats what I am getting : `Attempting to modify object outside of a write transaction - call beginWriteTransaction on an RLMRealm instance first`

Comment: that is other exception, no related to the first exception. You need follow realm rule when update field of realm, any update always inside realm.write block

Comment: so what are you saying is creating a write closure everytime there is an update ?

Comment: Hey You were right. I just had to follow realm rule. This worked. Great thing to learn man. Cheers!

Comment: Hey there a problem with this question again. Can you please help me here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50123907/realm-object-update-fails-on-write