# Realm object update fails on write

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, realm

I am trying to update a realm object everytime there is a value change in firebase. It just like whenever there's a change of object in the server it should automatically trigger a new write and update an obejct with primary key `uid`.

[**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50054762/updating-realm-object-having-primary-key) is a question I posted couple days ago. It gave me a momentary solution which worked for the moment but then following error started to pop up.

1. For the first run, everything ran fine and updated the object. But, as soon as I re-ran the program, It created a duplicate object with empty primary key.
2. It crashes the app saying that i am trying to overwrite the primarykey object.
3. I even got errors where it said the write transaction was already in process.

I am exactly following the Realm Documentation provided **[here](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#key-value-coding)**, but totally out of luck.

The code from where I am making update triggers to the realm object:

```
        FBDataservice.ds.REF_USERS.child(uuid).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.hasChild("credentials") {
            if let snap = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
                if let cred = snap["credentials"] as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
                    let u = User(userid: uuid, userData: cred)
//                        try! RealmService.uirealm.realm.write {
                        self.usercache.uid = uuid
                        self.usercache.name = u.name
                        self.usercache.bio = u.aboutme
                        if u.phoneNumer != nil {
                            self.usercache.phone = u.phoneNumer
                        }
                        self.usercache.email = u.email
                        self.usercache.username = u.username
                        if u.userPic != nil {
                            do {
                                self.usercache.imageL = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: u.userPic))
                            }catch {
                                print("The image doesnt exists")
                            }
                        }
//                            self.usercache.writeToRealm()
                    try! RealmService.uirealm.realm.write {
                        RealmService.uirealm.realm.create(UserData.self, value: ["uid":uuid], update: true)
                    }
//                            RealmService.uirealm.realm.add(self.usercache, update: true)



//                        }
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

My Realm Object :

```
class UserData : Object {

@objc dynamic var name: String? = nil
@objc dynamic var bio: String? = nil
@objc dynamic var email: String? = nil
@objc dynamic var username: String? = nil
@objc dynamic var phone: String? = nil
@objc dynamic var uid : String? = nil
@objc dynamic var imageL: Data? = nil

override static func primaryKey() -> String {
    return "uid"
}

}

extension UserData {


func writeToRealm(){
    try? RealmService.uirealm.realm.write {
        RealmService.uirealm.realm.add(self, update: true)
    }
}

func DeleteFromRealm(object: Results<UserData>){
    try? RealmService.uirealm.realm.write {
        RealmService.uirealm.realm.delete(object)
    }
}

}
```

The Realm Definition:

```
class RealmService {

static let uirealm = RealmService()

private var _initRS = try! Realm()

var realm: Realm! {
    return _initRS
}
}
```

I am really struggling to find the correct solution to this. Any help is really appreciated. If theres any more information to be provided for this issue. Please do let me know.

Comment: edit: ok I see it now. Maybe set update: false in the create method.

Comment: @u84six But wouldn't that just stop updating the current record in the object. Infact, I have another object aswell, and I have set it the same way and just call `writeToRealm()` method and it just updates it without any replication or errors.

Comment: I guess I’m a bit confused by the create with update vs the add with update in the extension. Why do you have both create and add?

Comment: @u84six If you see clearly, One is commented out. i was trying my hand on both. Its just that they are replicating the records

Comment: the create is not commented out and the add in the extension is not commented out

Comment: @u84six Thats correct. When I am using the `create`, I am not calling the method from extension. What can go wrong then

Comment: do you get the same error when just adding it vs create?

Comment: When I use create it just doesnt do anything. Not even update the value. And with write it replicates it

Comment: The question (and code) is unclear. It appears the uid of an existing user is passed to your function to load their data from Firebase. That uid is used as the *primary key* of a Realm object, which must be unique. If the user already exists (which means they would also already exist in Realm) then whenever it's created in Realm there would be an error since the user already exists. It's also unclear why a User object, 'u' is created and then never used, along with that, there's a third Realm object UserData which is never populated or used, other than the uid. Can you clean up the code?